# jQuery fading of seperate DIV contents, but only in current DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a setup as such...

```
<div class="racebox">
<div class="rb_logo"><a href="#" class="trigger"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/img      /new/rlogo_chm.png" width="250" height="184" /></a></div>
<div class="panel rb_bg"><img src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/img/new/bg_racebox.png" width="250" height="184" /></div>
</div>
```

I am using this to change the opacity of the second div inside of the racebox container:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // OPACITY OF DIV SET TO 0%
    $(".panel").css("opacity","0.0");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".trigger").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 100%
    $(".panel").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, "slow");
},function(){});

// ON MOUSE OUT
$(".trigger").mouseout(function () {
    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 0%
    $(".panel").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, "slow");
});
});
```

This works fine, but I want to have multiple instances of this "racebox" container, and I'm pretty sure this script will fade ALL of the targets divs instead of the current one only. Any suggestions on how to set this up so it only fades the div inside the current container?

Fairly new to jQuery, sorry if I'm missing something super basic.

Answer (score 0):

use this to traverse the dom relative to current target

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // OPACITY OF DIV SET TO 0%
    $(".panel").css("opacity", "0.0");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".trigger").hover(function() {

        // SET OPACITY TO 100%
        // current hovered .trigger - get parent - find sibling with .panel class
        $(this).parent().siblings(".panel").stop().animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, "slow");
    }, function() {});

    // ON MOUSE OUT
    $(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
        // SET OPACITY BACK TO 0%
        $(this).parent().siblings(".panel").stop().animate({
            opacity: 0.0
        }, "slow");
    });
});​
```

Or pass in context in your selector

```
$(".panel",$(this).closest('.racebox'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to the following

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // OPACITY OF DIV SET TO 0%
    $(".panel").css("opacity","0.0");

    // ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".trigger").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 100%
    this.parent().next().stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, "slow");
},function(){});

// ON MOUSE OUT
$(".trigger").mouseout(function () {
    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 0%
    this.parent().next().stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, "slow");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the case use $(this) instead of .panel

```
// ON MOUSE OVER
    $(".trigger").hover(function () {

    // SET OPACITY TO 100%
    $(this).parent().find('.panel').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, "slow");
},function(){});

// ON MOUSE OUT
$(".trigger").mouseout(function () {
    // SET OPACITY BACK TO 0%
    $(this).parent().find('.panel').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.0
    }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Had to move the trigger class from the image to the div it was inside of, then used that last bit from @sushanth

Thanks all!!!